# Half Angle Identities ???

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

If $\sin{x \over 2}={2 \over 3}$, $0 \le x \le {\pi \over 2}$, evaluate $$\cos x$$

I'm not sure how to start. I have graphed $\sin{x \over 2}={2 \over 3}$ on a cartesian plane but I am stuck. Am I supposed to set $\cos x$ to a half identity?

The final answer is supposed to be $1 \over 9$

Comment: You can use $$\sin(x/2)=\sqrt{\frac{1-\cos x}{2}}$$ for $0<x<2\pi$.

Answer (score 3):

Hint:

Use formula $\cos(x)=1-2\sin^2({x\over2})$

Answer (score 0):

$sin^2(x/2)+cos^2(x/2)=1$ so $\cos^2(x/2)=\frac{5}{9}$ by double angle formula we know $2cos^2(x)-1=cos(2x)$ so by substituting valuue for $cos(x/2)$ we get $cos(x)=\frac{1}{9}$ . Hope its clear.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose that $t=\frac{x}{2}$, then I can restate the problem as

If $\sin t=\frac{2}{3}$, $0\le 2t \le \frac{\pi}{2}$, evaluate $\cos 2t$